# Compile pthread on ARM Without any OS

Tags: c, eclipse, arm, pthreads, cortex-m

I'm Trying to compile [Kvazaar](https://github.com/ultravideo/kvazaar) on ARM processor (Cortex M3) Without linux or any OS just pure C.

I'm using Eclipse Cpp neon on windows 10 and [GNU ARM Eclipse](http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/).
When I'm building the project, I got an Error "unknown type name 'pthread_mutex_t'" ...

Comment: pthread is a functionality of a family of OSes, namely Unix. So to use pthread, you need at least Unix-like OS.

Comment: Well, I find it unlikely your Cortex-M3 has NEON?  Even so, you need an OS of sorts to do scheduling if you want pre-emptive threading (probably what the library assumes)?  Otherwise, you could try to port to co-routine libraries.  But I think your Cortex-M3 is going to have a hard time encoding/decoding HEVC video in an efficient way.  The project sound doomed to me given the little information we have.

Comment: Eclipse neon is just the latest version of eclipse!